# Theorem for the higher derivative of f(x(t),y(t))?

Tags: real-analysis

currently I'm interested in the higher-order derivatives of $f(x(t),y(t))$, assuming that $f(u,v)$ is continuous $\forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}$ and all necessary derivatives exist. In the process, I've found something like these
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{2x} = \lim\limits_{u,v\to x} \sum_{k=0}^{2} \binom{n}{k}\frac{d^{n}}{du^k dv^{n-k}} e^{u+v},~\text{(obviously)}
$$
$$
\frac{d^8}{dx^8} e^{x^x} = \lim\limits_{u,v\to x} \sum_{k=0}^{8} \binom{n}{k} \frac{d^{n}}{du^k dv^{n-k}} e^{u^v},
$$
$$
\frac{d^9}{dx^9} I_2(x^2) = \lim\limits_{u,v\to x} \sum_{k=0}^{9} \binom{n}{k} \frac{d^{n}}{du^k dv^{n-k}} I_2(uv),
$$
which then raises me a question, can 
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x(t),y(t)) \mathop{=}\limits^{?} \lim\limits_{u,v \to t} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{d^{n}}{du^k dv^{n-k}} f(x(u),y(v)).
$$
If can, what is (are) the underlying theorem(s)?

P/S: $I_v(x)$ specifies the modified Bessel function of the first kind [Ref.Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but what does $I_2(x^2)$ mean?

Comment: Hi, it's the modified Bessel function of the first kind. I've just added in my question, thank you for noticing this.